# my Apple push Service doesn't work ... I already created a new one and I still don't receive notifications. Does anyone know what could be happening?

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native, certificate, apple-push-notifications

Good afternoon guys, anyone there with experience with apple bureaucracies x pushNotifications x certificates x react native?

My app's Apple Push Services certificate expired the 1/10 and the app stopped receiving notifications. I already created another ... but nothing done.
Both me and the customers still don't receive push notifications.

Does anyone know what might be happening?

Answer (score 1):

Just creating a new APNS certificate wont work. You will need to replace the old certificate which you must still be using for generating the Push Notifications from APNS gateway with the New Certificate you just created.

Answer (score 0):

After analyzing the code I saw that the problem was related to the certificate that was not attached to the FireBase, which in turn was sending pushnotifications